# When might Google NodeApi.getLocalNode return null?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I love the concept of Pre-launch Testing, but my Wear app has been crashing in the testing while still working with real devices. Is that presumably because there are no Wear devices connected to the test devices? (I assume they're not).

Here's the error I get on a call to getLocalNode. I cannot find any documentation as to when getNode might be null and am just guessing that in earlier versions of Play it might be null if the local Node is not connected to any other nodes.

Can anybody either confirm/deny this or point me to the relevant code in 9.x and 8.x of Google Play Services NodeApi?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node.getId()' on a null object reference
    at com.pipperpublishing.refwatch.RefWatchUtil$4.onResult(RefWatchUtil.java:329)
    at com.pipperpublishing.refwatch.RefWatchUtil$4.onResult(RefWatchUtil.java:326)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Here's the relevant code which is modeled closely on one of the samples:

```
 public static void fetchLocalDataMap(final GoogleApiClient client,
                                         final String dataPath,
                                         final FetchLocalDataMapCallback callback) {
        Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(client).setResultCallback(
                //get the local node asynchronously and then call back to get local data
                new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult getLocalNodeResult) {
                        String localNode = getLocalNodeResult.getNode().getId();
                        Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                                .scheme("wear")
                                .path(dataPath)
                                .authority(localNode)
                                .build();
                        //get only locally created (this node's) data
                        Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem(client, uri)
                                .setResultCallback(new DataItemResultCallback(callback));

                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

By the way, there is no suggestion in any of the documentation or samples that getLocalNodeResult.getNode() could ever return null :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Sterling Udell](https://plus.google.com/u/0/114141353172612328217)for this suggestion: the problem occurs with earlier versions of Android (5.0/5.1) or possibly Google Play (9.0) when Android Wear is not installed. Apparently in later versions this call will at least return your local node, connected or not.